# Size of QGroupBox decorations

Tags: qt, qt4, coding-style

I need to calculate exact width of QGroupBox. I have the width of its child, but I struggle to calculate width of QGroupBox decorations (meaning `total_size - children_size - layout_space`). The group box has exactly one child in a QBoxLayout.

Currently I do it in a following way:

```
int width = layout()->contentsMargins().left() +
          layout()->contentsMargins().right() +
          6;                                     // <--- magic number

width += child->maximumWidth();
```

I got the '6' from trial and error and it works on my system's style (KDE's Oxygen) but I'd like to get it in a platform independent manner.

Is there any way to obtain it?

Comment: Magic number comes from layoutSpacing property of a layout.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `QWidget::frameSize()` on the QGroupBox? This should return the full size of the widget including any decoration.

Comment: I've tried it, but it always returns QSize(100, 30). No matter what's the actual size of the group box.

Comment: Sorry for late reply - I didn't notice your comment. frameGeometry() returns QRect(0,0 100x30) so it's the same as frameSize().